# How do I use std::cout with Eclipse CDT's Unit Testing support?

Tags: unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

If I use std::cout in my simple unit test in Eclipse CDT, I get the error message:
"XML parse error: Content is not allowed in prolog."

However, if I delete the line with the "cout" message then the tests run correctly.  It appears that the debug message I am printing to the terminal is interfering with the unit testing output such that the "C/C++ Unit Test" window in Eclipse is not able to parse the unit testing output.

My question is, how can I use the Unit Test support in Eclipse's CDT if my code contains some cout debugging messages?  Can the unit testing output be sent to a different location (like a temporary file) so that it is separate from the cout/debug/log messages printed to the terminal?

EDIT:
For example, if I use the example 25 in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/fixture/global.html:

```c
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE example
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>

//____________________________________________________________________________//

struct MyConfig {
    MyConfig()   { std::cout << "global setup\n"; }
    ~MyConfig()  { std::cout << "global teardown\n"; }
};

//____________________________________________________________________________//

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE( MyConfig );

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_case )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( true );
}

//____________________________________________________________________________//
```

then I get the error "XML parse error: Content is not allowed in prolog." in Eclipse. This seems to be caused by the Eclipse Unit Test tool not being able to parse the output containing "global setup".  So the question is: how can continue to use this example with debug messages printed while getting Eclipse's Unit Test tool to parse the messages and show the unit test results?

Answer (score 4):

The communication between Eclipse CDT & Boost.Test is implemented via std::cout, so your code should not output anything else there. You should use BOOST_MESSAGE or print to std::cerr instead.

Unfortunately it is a limitation of Boost.Test and it should be extended to implement the feature you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame a similar problem with XML parse errors interfering with the test run by conditionally wrapping output to std::cout with CDATA tags for the unit test build:

```
#if defined(WRAP_XML_CDATA)
  output << "<![CDATA[";
#endif
```

...

```
#if defined(WRAP_XML_CDATA)
  output << "]]>";
#endif
```

This stops the output of your program being parsed as XML.